# Prevent updateUIView() from being called in UIRepresentableView?

Tags: swiftui, lottie, uiviewrepresentable

I *think* I need to change a boolean in a `UIRepresentableView` before removing it from the `ContentView` but can't find a way, since I can't mutate the struct properties.

Why do I need that? Because I need to prevent `updateUIView()` from being called one last time before the view being released.

So probably this is an XY problem... anyway, I'm lost.

---

I have a model like this:

```
class PlayerModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    @Published var lottie: [LottieView]
```

Where `LottieView` is this:

```
struct LottieView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var name: String
    var loopMode: LottieLoopMode = .playOnce
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieView>) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieView>) {
        uiView.subviews.forEach({ sub in
            sub.removeFromSuperview()
        })
        
        let animationView = AnimationView()
        animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        uiView.addSubview(animationView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.widthAnchor),
            animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.heightAnchor)
        ])

        animationView.animation = Animation.named(name, animationCache: LRUAnimationCache.sharedCache)
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animationView.loopMode = loopMode
        animationView.play()
    }
}
```

In my `ContentView` I only display a `LottieView` if there's a recent one in the published array:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model: PlayerModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // ...
                
                if let lottie = model.lottie.last {
                    lottie
                }
                
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now this works ok, but when in the model I remove the last `LottieView` from the published array, the `updateUIView()` func is called one last time by SwiftUI, resulting in the animation being recreated again just before the `LottieView` is removed from the view, resulting in a visible flicker.

So I thought I'd add a boolean that I could update just before removing the last `LottieView` from the published array, and do an if/else in the `updateUIView()`, but... is this even possible? I can't find a way.

Ideally I would just have the animation view created in `makeUIView()` and nothing done in `updateUIView()` but this is not possible, I need to remove the subviews first, otherwise the previous shown animation is not replaced by the new one.

Comment: Generally, in SwiftUI, you don't hold a collection of views in a view model. Rather, you hold a collection of data objects, that you then iterate over (e.g. with `ForEach`) to create a view. Not sure if this would address your specific issue, but a good place to start is to following commong/best practices

Comment: @NewDev You are right. But even if I create the LottieViews in the view and have only objects in the published array in the model, I still have the same specific issue. And of course I'm opened to suggestions as how to change my architecture so that I can avoid this flicker thing.

Answer (score 0):

While I would still love to have someone give me a proper solution to my issue, or  tell me an alternative way of doing things, I found a workaround.

In the model, I was previously emptying the published array by doing

```
lottie = []
```

But if instead we do this:

```
lottie.removeAll()
```

We see no flicker anymore (however `updateView()` is still called!!).